# If $x$ is an integer and $x \ge 5$, then there's $y$ such that $x + y$ is a perfect square with $x > y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

$y < 5 \le x$ by hypothesis. Let $y = -x$.

Then, $-x + x = 0$. Since $0$ is a perfect square, we are done.

I am not sure if this proof would fly. Please, tell me what you think.

Comment: I expect that $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be non-negative, or even positive integers.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's right. I forgot about that.

Comment: The problem in the title does _not_ state that $y<5$. Another way of formulating the question is "There is a perfect square between $x$ and $2x$ for any $x\geq5$."

Comment: The problem almost certainly wants $y$ positive, otherwise $y=-x$ is always fine, but a bit silly.

Comment: If the instructor had forgotten to specify that $y$ is a non-negative integer, then the argument would be perfectly correct.  Whether it would fly might depend on the personality of the grader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem almost certainly wants $0\leq y<x$.

Let $v=\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor$. If $v^2=x$ then you are done, since $y=0$. So assume $v^2+1\leq x$. Let $y=(v+1)^2-x$. Prove that $y<x$ using the fact that $2\leq v$ so $2v\leq v^2$.

The problem might even want $y>0$, which requires some extra care but isn't much harder. That's because if $y=0$ is allowed, then the theorem would be true for $x=4$ and $x=3,$ too.

Comment: I am confused a bit. If we assume $v^2 + 1 \le x$ and let $x = 1$, wouldn't our assumption be incorrect seeing as how $v^2 = x = 1$?

Comment: Well, we assumed $x\geq 5$. @Erbolat